# Price is not updating when dropdown is selected for configurable items

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, items

I am having a small issue in where the price is not being updated on Magento 1.9. When I select a drop down selection the price is still fixed to the configurable price. I have learned that Magento does not take the prices of the simple items. Which I am ok with, but I don't understand there reasoning behind it. How do I go about fixing this issue?I added the console error that I get that may help.[image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and my browser console was showing

> TypeError: Product.OptionsPrice is not a constructor

I figured out the my theme was not adding `product_options.js` file to catalog category default page and catalog product view page.

So I made two changes in `my-template/default/layout/catalog.xml`

1- Injected `product_options.js` inside `catalog_category_default` handle

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

2- Injected `product_options.js` inside `catalog_product_view` handle

`<action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script>`

Comment: I tried that, but then it broke page viewing. The error I get is [Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)]. I it seems to be that that something in product_options.js or catalog.xml is not loading correctly.